# How to grab one MSMQ message at a time from the queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, console-application, msmq

I am using Console application (C#) to read the MSMQ messages.

The following is the working code.

**C# (Console Application)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     MessageQueue[] myQueueArray = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("192.0.0.1");

                    if (myQueueArray != null)
                    {                    
                        foreach (MessageQueue mq in myQueueArray)
                        {
                            if (mq.QueueName.Contains("myqueue"))
                            {
                                myQueue = mq;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (myQueue != null)
                        {

                            Message[] messageList = myQueue.GetAllMessages();
                            if (messageList != null)
                            {                           
                                foreach (Message msg in messageList)
                                {    
                                 //doing some operation with the message
                                }    
                            }    
                        }
                     }
                 }
```

The above code is working perfectly.

But I want to read the MSMQ messages one by one means **how do i grab one message at a time from the queue?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `MessageQueue.Receive` to dequeue single message at a time, see this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8yd39fz(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also use `BeginReceive` and `ReceiveCompleted` event to get the notification, see this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.receivecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Edit**

This [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.endreceive(v=vs.110).aspx) link that has very simple sample code that helped the OP to dequeue the message from MSMQ (pointed through comment)

Comment: Thanks. My issue has been resolved. I have found the following url. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.endreceive(v=vs.110).aspx